# Computer shuts down without warning

Tags: laptop, cpu, shutdown, fan, overheating

I have a problem with my Packard Bell EasyNote TS11HR laptop.

Whenever I play any games, my computer just shuts down after 5mins playing. Without any warning at all.

I already did some research on this, I checked if I have enough ram, and I concluded 6 GB should do, as well as my Graphics card: a NVDIA GeForce GT540M with 2 GB VRAM.

I also cleaned out my fan with compressed air on the side of my computer (because I can't find any way to get into the fan itself).

The computer is only less than a year old, from last January.

But still it shuts down, only while playing games, and I suspect it's because of my CPU, but i have now struggled with this for one month, and I'm really lost.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a tool like [hwmonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) to check to see if the CPU may be overheating.

---

Update:

If the computer's CPU is overheating and the computer is less than a year old, it is faulty and should be replaced by the retailer under warranty (depending on consumer laws in your country)

The alternative is to take it for repair or attempt yourself to disassemble the CPU cooling system, clean it, replace any defective parts and reassemble (with new thermal paste between CPU and heatsink). I wouldn't attempt this unless you are confident of success.

See [Heat Transfer Paste reapplication](https://superuser.com/q/348311/52492)

Comment: i know that it is overheating, but i need a solution for this.

Comment: In that case: Download the technician manual (not the user manual) for the laptop. It will show you how to open the laptop. Once that is done check that the fan is running and that the heatsinks are properly connected.

Comment: :Kevin see updated answer.

Comment: Awesome answer. But you know, the thing is. There is no Manual to open into the fan. Searched all over the internet, aswell as Packard Bell's website. Can't find anything, anywhere.

Comment: http://ant0ny.net/packard-bell-easynote-ts44-hr-service-manual/  File PackardBellEasyNoteTS11HR.pdf

Comment: Laptops are fiddly to take apart and reassemble. I take photos as I disassemble, I label parts or tape them to a diagram. Make notes as needed. Being extra patient can help to prevent permanent damage to fragile plastic parts. Look for screws hidden under labels and in hard to see places. You may have to use force to lever out snap-fit parts.

Comment: Note: Opening it while it's under warranty may void said warranty.

Comment: Overheating is most often just dust.  You might just try blowing some canned air through any vents or lifting the case to see if that helps.  But unless you're really confident you can get it all back together, I'd be careful about any further disassembly and send it back to the manufacturer.  I was confident enough and had all the right tiny screwdrivers when I took one apart a few years ago. But I was surprised at how hard it was to do it without breaking anything and then how hard it was to reassemble.  And I still ended up losing a screw.

Comment: +1 to both. If under warrenty. Return to shop. If not go slow. Look at the picture in the manual (start chapter 3-31).  Use tape to keep the correct screw near the correct hole.  When in doubt then pictures are a very good idea.

Comment: I thank you all. The chapter 3-31 is very nice. I try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Install a tool like http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/">RealTemp and/or GPU-Z and run it on a secondary screen while (full-screen) gaming.

Note the values **before** the computer shuts down.  Then check how how things are allowed to get.

If you can not connect a second screen, try running the game in a window.

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is still under warranty, you should contact the manufacturer. Your model might have a known thermal design flaw that has been corrected or where there is remedy. Had this happen with a Lenovo T410. The downside is of course that you might not have a laptop for a while when you send it in.